# Where is the blacksmith?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

I've just started a new game, and haven't really left Default Village that much, but I did manage to acquire some Grindstones.

[image]

I am apparently supposed to take them to the Blacksmith, but I've checked out what I belive are the shops in Default Village, and can't seem to find my way to a blacksmith.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but **how do I find the Blacksmith?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a blacksmith in Sunset Castle, which is the first place to the north of Default Village. The grindstones are used to level up the blacksmith, which increases your chance of success when trying to upgrade your equipment. It also increases the maximum level to which the blacksmith can improve the items.

If you need more detailed information about the values of upgrading at the blacksmith, you can have a look at the [wiki page for the Blacksmith](http://knightsofpenandpaper.wikia.com/wiki/Blacksmith).

The recommended level for Sunset Castle is 7, so just keep playing a little and you will get to the blacksmith soon.

Comment: Ah well that makes sense. I suppose I was just a bit confused by getting the item so early but not really being able to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Blacksmith is present in all cities other than Default Village.